# Can we create snow pipe for association

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, mock-aws-s3

ex.
The JSON format for snow pipe is as follows:

```
{
 {
   id:      1, 
   title:   xyz, 
   body:    pqs, 
   table_B: [
              {
                id:       1, 
                comment:  "ptr"
              },
              {
                id:       1, 
                comment:  "LMN"
              }
            ]
 }
}
```

How do I store this attribute to two different tables on Snowflake using snow pipe:

Snowflake Table A

```
id | title | body |
-------------------
1. | XYZ.  | PQS. |
-------------------
```

Snowflake  Table B

```
id | comment | a_id |
---------------------
1. | ptr     | 1    |
---------------------
2. | LMN.    | 1    |
---------------------
```

Comment: Load the data into a single staging table using Snowpipe and then write the data to the correct target tables using SQL, tasks, etc?

Comment: Snowpipe ingests raw data...then use streams and tasks to split the data into your 2 target tables.